# Can't access my remote ftp server anymore

Tags: networking, internet, ftp

I'm running win 10 and I tried setting up my ftp server that could be visited from outside of my local network. I did exactly how it said in this [tutorial](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-set-and-manage-ftp-server-windows-10).

and it worked fine. I was able to connect to my ftp server from outside my network. But then I had couple of issues and I wanted a fresh start so I deleted my ftp server and made a new one. This time I didn't have to make firewall exception because it was already made.

But now I can't connect to this server from outside my network. Everything seems to be set up just as the first time but every time I try to connect from outside I get "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx refused to connect". Does anyone have any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Have you tried turning off the firewall completely?

Comment: yeah I did and it still didn't work

Comment: Well, the next thing might be to make sure your iis/ftp site is actually running/active (not just created) and not using SSL. Short of that, your next culprits are likely (obviously) your port forwarding/client settings (esp. if you use DHCP).